# How to fire "onmouseenter" only if cursor came from outside of that element

Tags: javascript, css

I have 2 images, `one` and `two`

On hover of `one`, the `two` is displayed, and `one` is hidden

And then, if I clicked `two`, it should hide and show the `one` again

So far all okay

BUT, problem is, mouse is already on the `one` image so `onmouseenter` triggers again. I want it to trigger only if mouse came from outside of image without jQuery

Just like the Chat icon [here](https://chaty.app/) on bottom-right

```js
document.getElementById("one").onmouseenter = function onmouseoverRobot() {
    document.querySelector("#two").style = 'display:inline-block !important'
    document.querySelector("#one").style = 'display:none !important'
}


document.getElementById("two").onclick = function X_CHAT_01() {

    document.querySelector("#two").style = 'display:none !important'
    
    document.querySelector("#one").style = 'display:inline-block !important'
}
```

```html
<img id='one' src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSoMUKwCL1uINRV035jkpfQzAbiObKqraXA6369mZBe0To0UuWP'>

<img id='two' style='display:none' src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSMYIpY4d8KlTzhAd38KZW8DIadeEV59WtLlxeIH3PS4uPXL0RP'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution that doesn't require event listeners mangling is to add a boolean indicator that tells if the chat has been enabled or not.

```js
var chatEnabled = false;

var one = document.getElementById('one');
var two = document.getElementById('two');

one.onmouseenter = function onmouseoverRobot() {
  if (chatEnabled) {
    return;
  }
  two.style = 'display:inline-block !important';
  one.style = 'display:none !important';
};

one.onmouseout = function onmouseoutRobot() {
  chatEnabled = false;
};

two.onclick = function X_CHAT_01() {
  chatEnabled = true;
  two.style = 'display:none !important';
  one.style = 'display:inline-block !important';
};
```

Please, take a look at the [demo](https://jsbin.com/wohaseteyo/edit?js,output).

Comment: please fix the inline snippet, you Demo links works perfectly though, accepting answer

Comment: Yep, corrected and updated the link to the demo.
Looks good now?

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid the `mouseenter` event firing when you show the image try removing the listener and then adding it back after a `mouseleave` event.

1. `img#one`:`mouseenter` - Remove `mouseenter` listener from `img#one`. Hide `img#one` and show `img#two`.
2. `img#two`:`click` -  Show `img#one` and hide `img#two`.
3. `img#one`:`mouseleave` - Add `mouseenter` listener to `img#one`.

You can also use one-time listeners for a simpler flow.

```
const onMouseEnter = function() {
    hide(one)
    show(two)
    two.addEventListener("click", onClick, { once: true })
}

const onClick = function() {
    one.addEventListener("mouseleave", onMouseLeave, { once: true })
    hide(two)
    show(one)
}

const onMouseLeave = function() {
    one.addEventListener("mouseenter", onMouseEnter, { once: true })
}

one.addEventListener("mouseenter", onMouseEnter, { once: true })
```